# Unable to set a default value for a CCK field

Tags: 6, entities

I am trying to set a default value for a CCK Multi Select field tried with PHP code

```
return array(
  0 => array('value' => "ONE"),
  1 => array('value' => "TWO"),
);
```

and without PHP Code by just selecting the values (after adding to Allowed Values) with required ON & OFF but still nothing gets selected in select drop down.

Comment: you can set the default value by editing the field, there is an option to select the default value..

Comment: Yes I have done the same with PHP option and without PHP option but I still dont see any default values in my nodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded CCK modules and this issue wasnt there in new module.
May be it was a bug in the version that I used before.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try by creating a new (text)field & choosing widget as select list.
then put in allowed values
0|a
1|b
2|c
(putting 0|a in one line,1|b in other so on..)
& number of values to unlimited & save
by editing, select default values from drop down & save.
hope it helps..